# What are filetypes encompassed in two hashtags in Unix?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu, hashtag

I'm fairly new to Linux, and decided to clean up some directories. Found files encompassed in two # (#random.c#, #nfirst.c#)...what do those hashtags mean? And when i try to rm those files via terminal, it treats the hashtag as a comment...I've tried that double hyphen bypass (rm -- #first.c#) but it doesn't work. So could someone please explain to me what those files are and how are they created/ removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are temporary files, likely created by the `emacs` text editor when it autosaves.

To remove them, you can do `rm \#first.c\#`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably files created by emacs as backup files when you quit a buffer you haven't written.

Put a backslash in front of the hash to delete it

rm \#random.c\#

Answer (score 0):

These are probably temporary backups from your editor. To remove them in a shell you may want to backslash-escape the `#`, so try

```
  rm \#first.c\#
```